# how to use JWT for angular js based application and backend is Codeigniter?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, jwt

I have developed an application in which client side is AngularJS and server side is Code Igniter based API.

I want to implement JSON Web Token (JWT) in my application for security. I have tried to learn that but can't understood in proper manner.

I need help in How to use it & what are the fundamentals for that ?

Comment: This isn't a  tutorial service. You need to be far more specific isolating problems and questions. See [ask]

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know. @charlietfl